# Combining XmlSerializer and XmlWriter?

Tags: c#

In addition to a list of objects I am serializing to an xml file using C#'s XmlSerializer, I would like to store a few more independent elements (mainly strings from textboxes) in the same xml.

```
    public static void SaveBehaviors(ObservableCollection<Param> listParams)
    {
        XmlSerializer _paramsSerializer = new XmlSerializer(listParams.GetType());
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
        path += "\\test.xml";
        using (TextWriter writeFileStream = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            _paramsSerializer.Serialize(writeFileStream, listParams);

            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(writeFileStream))
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Foo"); //test entry...
                writer.WriteAttributeString("Bar", "Some & value");
                writer.WriteElementString("Nested", "data");
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }
    }
```

However, deserializing "test.xml" results in an error because of the added element. I suppose writing in the serialized xml file is prohibited and should be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Don't do that.

If you need to serialize more than your ObservableCollection, then define a containing type and *serialize that*.

```
public static void SaveBehaviors(ObservableCollection<Param> listParams) 
{ 
    XmlSerializer _paramsSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ContainingType)); 
    var c = new ContainingType(listParams); 
    c.ExtraInformation = whatever....; 

    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); 
    path += "\\test.xml"; 
    using (TextWriter writeFileStream = new StreamWriter(path)) 
    { 
        _paramsSerializer.Serialize(writeFileStream, c); 
    } 
}
```

Use the XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but I very strongly recommend not using the stream to do it.  By re-opening the stream in a writer (serializer will close it when finished) you start at the beginning of the while, this is why you are getting MalFormed xml.

What you CAN do, is re-load the stream into an XmlDocument.  Here is an edited function that may work better for you.

```
public static void SaveBehaviors(ObservableCollection<Param> listParams)
{
    XmlSerializer _paramsSerializer = new XmlSerializer(listParams.GetType());
    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
    path += "\\test.xml";
    using (TextWriter writeFileStream = new StreamWriter(path))
    {
        _paramsSerializer.Serialize(writeFileStream, listParams);

        using (XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument())
        {
            doc.Load(path);//load from the saved document
            XmlNode fooNode = doc.CreateElement("foo");//create node
            XmlAttribute fooAtt = doc.CreateAttribute("bar");//create attribute
            fooAtt.InnerText = "some att data";//set data
            fooNode.InnerText = "some node text";//set data
            fooNode.Attributes.Append(fooAtt);//add attribute to node
            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(fooNode);//add node to document
            doc.Save(path);//save the changes made
        }
    }
}
```

You COULD use an XmlWriter for this, but the danger is making sure that the WriteStream is putting the data in the correct location.  I personally dont know enough about XmlWriter to do this, at the moment.  It would take quite a bit of experimentation and looking at my output files.  Its much easier to just use the built in formatting that XmlDocument provides.

Answer (score 0):

It's not prohibited, you're just writing an illegal xml file with multiple root tags - you need to write out an initial element tag before you write the serialized object and then close that tag once you've written out your custom elements - in the code pattern you used you'll need to write this tag and closing tag manually

Comment: I do of course second the other comments that this is less than advisable -  mixing serialized objects and custom xml earns you the responsibility of keeping track of who parses what, which can quickly become a giant pain